# Get sub-columns (id) from a SELECT QUERY to be used in another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: `items` and `items_meta`. In one query, I would like to select all items from the items table that match some conditions.

```
SELECT id,name,price description FROM items 
WHERE {some conditions are true};
```

I would like to also select all rows in the items_meta which match the `id` of the items in the first query. This will be used for another purpose not directly related to the first query.

```
SELECT meta_name, meta_value,COUNT(*) FROM items_meta
WHERE item_id IN ({the ids from the previous query})
GROUP BY meta_name, meta_value;
```

My current implementation is to loop through the first results using PHP and create a list of the `id` to be used in the second query.

```
foreach ($items as $item){
    $items_id[] = $item["id"];
}

$IDs = implode(",", $items_id);
```

I think there should be an sql approach better than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join` or `in`:

```
SELECT im.meta_name, im.meta_value, COUNT(*)
FROM items i JOIN
     items_meta im
     ON im.item_id = i.id
WHERE {some conditions are true}
GROUP BY im.meta_name, im.meta_value;
```

Comment: This solution is what I actually thought at first. The only challenge is that the first query is actually a simplified form of a complex query which JOINS several tables to produce the result. Repeating these joins in the second query actually makes it more complex and processor intensive.

Comment: I also thought of creating a temporary table using the first query, then use your approach. The reason I dismissed that idea was because it introduced extra complexity. I had to insert the data into the temporary table, then select all the results again as my first output. I would be glad if there's a way to insert the data and return it as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT id,
   name,
   price,
   description,
   meta_name,
   meta_value,
   COUNT(*)
FROM items
INNER JOIN items_meta ON items_meta.item_id = items.id
WHERE {SOME conditions ARE TRUE}
GROUP BY meta_name,
     meta_value;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your solution works, but not the way I want it to. As I said in my question, I actually need two different results for two different purposes; but your solution provides only one. The results will be passed to the template as two different variables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a form and retrieve the id of your item you could do this:

```
    <?php 

// $db being the PDO connection

$stmt_items = $db->query("SELECT id,name,price description FROM items WHERE {some conditions are true};");
$stmt_items_meta = $db->prepare("SELECT meta_name, meta_value,COUNT(*) FROM items_meta WHERE item_id = ".$_POST['id']." GROUP BY meta_name, meta_value;");
$stmt_count_items_meta = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items_meta WHERE item_id = ".$_POST['id'].";");

while ($item = $stmt_items->fetch()) {

    // do things with your first query

    if ($stmt_count_items_meta->fetchColumn() > 0){ 
        $stmt_items_meta->execute();
        // do things with your second query
    }
}
```

If not:

```
<?php 

$stmt_items = $db->query("SELECT id,name,price description FROM items WHERE {some conditions are true};");


while ($item = $stmt_items->fetch()) {
    $stmt_items_meta = $db->prepare("SELECT meta_name, meta_value,COUNT(*) FROM items_meta WHERE item_id = ".$item['id']." GROUP BY meta_name, meta_value;");
    $stmt_count_items_meta = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items_meta WHERE item_id = ".$item['id'].";");
    // do things with your first query

    if ($stmt_count_items_meta->fetchColumn() > 0){ 
        $stmt_items_meta->execute();
        // do things with your second query
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)